Is there any way to add Ubuntu and Debian official cloud repository to virt-builder config file?
I want to obtain cloud images directly from these repositories instead of using this source: http://builder.libguestfs.org/. The Debian and Ubuntu images provided there are outdated. How can I add these repositories, which are updated and have supported formats, instead?

Ubuntu Cloud Images
Debian Cloud Images

